# Having problems identifying my mistake

Tags: sql, select

The tables which are  already created and unmodifiable are Book and Author.

Book (*Title*, Price, Yeareleased)

Author(AName,*btitle,position*)

Italized are the keys
and Btitle in Author is a foreign key that references Book(Title).

My SQL query:

```
   select distinct AName
   from Author
   where position in (2,3) AND position<>1
   group by AName
```

When I run this I get all the authors that have a book in position 2 or 3. Which is what I want but I'm only trying to get those authors which have a position 2 or 3 for all there books.
Essentially returning every author who was in the 2nd or 3rd position in all the books.

Comment: This schema needs to be fixed. Should be something like: `Book(book_id, Title, Price, Yearreleased, position, author_id)` and `Author(author_id, AName)`, where `book_id` and `author_id` are auto-increment primary keys. The `author_id` in `Book` is a foreign key to `Author`. Don't use `Title` as a primary key, because there can be different books with the same title.

Comment: Shouldn't book have an author_id column? And I hope btitle does not mean "book title". You need to rethink your model

Comment: I'm currently using a set schema for this practice. And btitle does refer to book title. I was just wondering how would I go about to only displaying those whom position was 2 or 3 for all books

Comment: As an aside your `position<>1` condition is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
select distinct AName
from @Author
where position in (2,3) 
except 
select distinct AName
from @Author
where position not in (2,3)
```

It makes a set of those authors who are in position 2 and 3 and then removes the ones who has another position.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear whether someone who co-wrote 2 books and was listed second on one and third on the other should be selected or not.  It is simpler to allow it; you can refine the query if you need the more stringent condition.

One way to answer this query makes the key observation that you're interested in authors for whom the count of the books they have written is equal to the count of the books where they are listed as second or third author.

Go for some TDQD — Test-Driven Query Design

#### Number of books each author wrote

```
SELECT Aname, COUNT(*) AS BookCount
  FROM Author
 GROUP BY AName
```

#### Number of books each author wrote as second or third author

```
SELECT Aname, COUNT(*) AS NonLeadAuthorCount
  FROM Author
 WHERE Position IN (2, 3)
 GROUP BY Aname
```

#### Join those two where the counts are identical

```
SELECT X.Aname
  FROM (SELECT Aname, COUNT(*) AS BookCount
          FROM Author
         GROUP BY AName
       ) AS X
  JOIN (SELECT Aname, COUNT(*) AS NonLeadAuthorCount
          FROM Author
         WHERE Position IN (2, 3)
         GROUP BY Aname
       ) AS Y
    ON X.BookCount = Y.NonLeadAuthorCount
```

---

An alternative way of looking at is 'the set authors who have written a book in position 2 or 3 minus the set of authors who have written a book where the position is neither 2 nor 3'.  For this, see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19579329/15168) by [jpw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175077/jpw).

Answer (score 1):

Trying to write standard SQL:

```
SELECT AName FROM (
   SELECT 
      AName, 
      COUNT(*) AS count_all,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Author AS aa WHERE aa.AName = a.AName AND position=2) AS count_2,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Author AS aa WHERE aa.AName = a.AName AND position=3) AS count_3,
   FROM Author AS a
   GROUP BY AName
) AS t
WHERE count_all = count_2
OR count_all = count_3
```

I hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select AName from Author where position=2 OR position=3 group by AName;
```

Comment: This lists the authors who have written a book in position 2 or 3; it does not exclude those who have also written a book in position 1 (or position 4, 5, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
and AName not in (select AName from Author where position != 2 and position != 3
```

Or something like that...